# Envio ao Pag Seguro

Tags: php

uma ajuda com `Pag Seguro`

Criei uma conta no `Pag Seguro do UOL` para o site.

Tenho o form abaixo

```
    <form method="post" target="pagseguro" 
action="https://www.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html">

      <!-- Campos obrigatórios -->
      <input name="receiverEmail" type="hidden" value="teste@gmail.com">
      <input name="currency" type="hidden" value="BRL">

      <!-- Itens do pagamento (ao menos um item é obrigatório) -->
      <input type="hidden" name="itemId1" value="70">
      <input type="hidden" name="itemDescription1" value="Publica">
      <input type="hidden" name="itemAmount1" value="55.77">
      <input type="hidden" name="itemQuantity1" value="1">
      <!-- Itens do pagamento (ao menos um item é obrigatório) --> 

      <!-- Código de referência do pagamento no seu sistema (opcional) -->
      <input name="reference" type="hidden" value="42">

      <!-- Informações de frete (opcionais) -->
      <input name="shippingType" type="hidden" value="1">
      <input name="shippingAddressPostalCode" type="hidden" value="36880000">
      <input name="shippingAddressStreet" type="hidden" value="Rua JB">
      <input name="shippingAddressNumber" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input name="shippingAddressComplement" type="hidden" value="Lote 06">
      <input name="shippingAddressDistrict" type="hidden" value="São Francisco">
      <input name="shippingAddressCity" type="hidden" value="Muriaé">
      <input name="shippingAddressState" type="hidden" value="MG">
      <input name="shippingAddressCountry" type="hidden" value="BRA">

      <!-- Dados do comprador (opcionais) -->
      <input name="senderName" type="hidden" value="Carlos Rocha">
      <input name="senderAreaCode" type="hidden" value="32">
      <input name="senderPhone" type="hidden" value="22222222">
      <input name="senderEmail" type="hidden" value="teste@oi.com.br">

      <!-- submit do form (obrigatório) -->
      <input class="formularios" type="image" name="submit" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/120x53-pagar.gif" alt="Pague com PagSeguro">
    </form>
```

Quando submeto o form, dá erro de time out.

Tem algum erro?

Esta faltando alguma coisa?

Sei que pode enviar via `cUrl`. Mas entende que dessa forma o Cliente do site terá que digitar seus dados no próprio site da loja e não no site da Pague Seguro o que poderá gerar desconfiança.

Comment: value="teste@gmail.com" este tem que ser o email da sua conta no pagseguro neh

Comment: isso. Só que aqui postei dados diferentes. A dúvida aqui é quanto a se falta algum campo ou atribuição de forma errada.

Comment: O do pagseguro está certo, mas porque não usa um código ajax que eles tem? Vou postar aqui pra ti

Comment: Bom. Poderia usar cUrl e Ajax ou Jquery. Mas assim o cliente não seria redirecionado para a pagina do Pag Seguro. Ou serea?

Comment: Hmm este meu tem que ter o token do pagseguro,  é um catalogo de produtos que estás a fazer ou apenas uma compra online?

Comment: Mas envia o token já ma primeira requisição? qual o nome do input? Porque neste formulário não estou enviando o token!

Comment: Loja Online que estou desenvolvendo!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40103/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-carlos-rocha).

Answer (score 0):

Baixa a Biblioteca do pagseguro  e aponte seu action do seu formulário para este script que postei abaixo,  coloque sua chave, e sete suas variáveis como gostar. acabei de testar com seu formulario e rodou perfeitamente

```
<?php 
 require_once "../pagseguro/ps/PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php";
 class CreatePaymentRequest 
 {
 public static function main()
 {

 $id_finan1 = 200;

 $nome = $_POST['senderName'];
 define("NOMER", $nome);
 $email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
 define("EMAIL", $email);
 $cpf = $_POST['rg'];
 define("CPF", $cpf);
 $tel1 = $_POST['senderPhone'];
 define("TEL1", $tel1);
 $cep = $_POST['cep'];
 define("CEP", $cep);
 $rua = $_POST['valor'];
 $rua = $_POST['endereco'];
 $num = $_POST['num'];
 $cmple = $_POST['cmple'];
 $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
 $estado = $_POST['uf'];
 $pais = 'BRA';
 $ddd = $_POST['senderAreaCode'];
 define("DDD", $ddd);
 $des = 'ola';

    $paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
    $paymentRequest->setCurrency("BRL");  
    $paymentRequest->addItem('12', 'Seu nome', 1, 20.00);
    $paymentRequest->setReference($id_finan1);
    $sedexCode = PagSeguroShippingType::getCodeByType('SEDEX');
    $paymentRequest->setShippingType($sedexCode);

    $nomee = NOMER;    $email = EMAIL;   $cpf = CPF;
    $tel1 = TEL1;      $cep = CEP;     
    $num = NUM;        $cmple = CMPLE; $ddd = DDD;  

     $des->description;
       $paymentRequest->setShippingAddress(
        $cep,
        $rua,
        $num,
        $id_solicitante,
        $bairro,
        $cidade,
        $estado,
        'BRA'
    );
        $nomer = $nomee;  
        $cpfr = $cpf; 
        $emailr = $email; 

        $paymentRequest->setSender(
        $nomer,
        $emailr,
        $ddd,
        $tel1,
        $cpfr,
        $cpfr
    );

    try {
  $credentials = new PagSeguroAccountCredentials("seuemail@gmail.com","sua   chave");
        $url = $paymentRequest->register($credentials);
        self::printPaymentUrl($url);
    } catch (PagSeguroServiceException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
   }
   public static function printPaymentUrl($url)
   { 
    if ($url) {
        echo "<h2>Criando requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o de pagamento</h2>";
        echo "<p>URL do pagamento: <strong>$url</strong></p>";
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=$url'>";
        //echo "<p><a title=\"URL do pagamento\" href=\"$url\">Ir para URL do pagamento.</a></p>";
    }
   } 
  }
   CreatePaymentRequest::main();
```

Comment: Como setar o action para uma classe? Assim mesmo? action="CreatePaymentRequestphp"?

Comment: não. colocando só o nome do arquivo com esse script acima action="arquivo.php"

Comment: Deu no mesmo CreatePaymentRequest.php ou arquivo.php. Não? CreatePaymentRequest.php contém esse código. Mas estarei enviando dados via post para uma classe sem a chamada a métodos. Isso que não entendi.

Comment: Desculpa.. no 1° comentario vc colocou junto o php e pensei que vc queria chamar a função por ali

Comment: Sim. voce pode enviar os dados via POST/GET sem chamar a função que ela ja vai funcionar.

Comment: é ai que mora o problema: não funcionou!

Comment: Qual erro ta dando ai?

Comment: Agora cheguei na página deles. Faltou enviar o email do PagSeguro.

Comment: Agora estou com uma outra dúvida: No caso do envio do valor do frete, como vocês fazem? Calculam o frete no próprio site e exibem ao cliente ou envia medidas de cada produto para o próprio pagseguro calcular o frete? A duvida é porque para calcular o frete de cada produto (item) em separado, a api dos correios irá considerar também um caixa para cada item do carrinho! Será que tem jeito de enviar o valor total de frete do pedido todo em vez de enviar item a item?

Comment: Carlos Eu aqui não uso pag seguro para vendas de produtos e sim pra serviço então não uso frete, mais o certo seria calcular no site antes do envio, acho eu.